# Compiling Qt using MSVC 2005 and dealing with SxS Windows

Tags: qt, dll, winsxs

A group I am working with is tasked with developing a new project using Qt.  However, we need to be able to link with C++ libraries from the MSVC 2005 world.  We will also need to integrate eventually with the MSVC-based build system, so it seems important to build Qt using MSVC.

I've recompiled Qt using MSVC 2005, and that works.  (if not as easily as it should be)  That will work on the box that actually compiled it.  However, it's a serious pain to use on different boxes for us since MSVC 2005 seems to always use slightly different SxS Windows DLL versions for the runtime.

We can't all get on the same patch levels for XP, MSVC because we're normally part of different groups with different targets for toolchain patch levels.

What's the easiest way to deal with this sort of issue?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I force a native application to use an older C runtime](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3097592/how-do-i-force-a-native-application-to-use-an-older-c-runtime)

Answer (score 1):

Qt is now available as [binary library](http://qt.developpez.com/binaires/en/) for Visual Studio 2005. You should give it a try in order to not have to compile Qt by yourself. This should work on every computer where Visual Studio 2005 is installed.

Comment: Thanks, but no OpenSSL in those builds.  Plus, I'd like to avoid downloading binaries from non-official sources.  If there was no other option, it'd be okay...  but it's not quite that serious.